# how to get rows satisfying certain condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
 name       strike

INFY        1000

INFY        1020

INFY        1040

INFY        1060

INFY        1080

INFY        1100

INFY        1120

INFY        1140

INFY        1160

INFY        1180

INFY        1200

INFY        1220
```

I have a dataframe containing columns name and strike,

for query `ltp = 1065` I want to return dataframe containing 6 rows

where three rows will have value greater than `ltp` and three rows will
have value lower than `ltp`

in this case

```
INFY        1020

INFY        1040

INFY        1060

INFY        1080

INFY        1100

INFY        1120
```

.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df
    name  strike  # ltp > strike
0   INFY    1000  # False
1   INFY    1020  # False                                 <-|
2   INFY    1040  # False                                 <-|
3   INFY    1060  # False                                 <-|
4   INFY    1080  # True <- this is the breakpoint, idx=4 <-|
5   INFY    1100  # True                                  <-|
6   INFY    1120  # True                                  <-|
7   INFY    1140  # True
8   INFY    1160  # True
9   INFY    1180  # True
10  INFY    1200  # True
11  INFY    1220  # True
```

Find the breakpoint with `argmin` and get 3 items below and 3 items above including the breakpoint:

```
>>> idx = df['strike'].lt(ltp).argmin()
>>> out = df['strike'].iloc[max(idx-3, 0):min(idx+3, len(df))]
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
1    1020
2    1040
3    1060
4    1080
5    1100
6    1120
Name: strike, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the index.

First of, create an empty dataframe: `results = pd.Dataframe()`
Then `for index in df.iterrows():`
And then if condition is reached (x > 1065), ask to append

```
df.loc[:,index-3], df.loc[:,index-2], df.loc[:,index-1],df.loc[:,index],df.loc[:,index+1], df.loc[:,index+2]
```